# Getting message to fate away after animating open

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a button that I want to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>.animate-show.ng-hide-add, 
                .animate-show.ng-hide-remove {
                  -webkit-transition:all linear 0.5s;
                  -moz-transition:all linear 0.5s;
                  -o-transition:all linear 0.5s;
                  transition:all linear 0.5s;
                  display:block!important;
                }

                .animate-show.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active,
                .animate-show.ng-hide-remove {
                  line-height:0;
                  opacity:0;
                  padding:0 10px;
                }

                .animate-show.ng-hide-add,
                .animate-show.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
                  line-height:20px;
                  opacity:1;
                  padding:10px;
                  border:1px solid black;
                  background:white;
                }

                .check-element {
                  padding:10px;
                  border:1px solid black;
                  background:white;
                }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div ng-app=App>
        <button ng-click="showme=true">Submit</button>
         <div class="check-element animate-show" ng-show="showme">
            I show up when the Submit button is clicked.
        </div>
    </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.3/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            angular.module('App', ['ngAnimate']);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It is working well:

[image]

But how do I get it to fade away after a few moments the same way it faded in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have setup a [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/MyYF0874whQ4Ta8At745?p=preview) that fades out the DIV 5 secs after submit button is clicked. Below is how it looks:

```
var myApp = angular.module('App', ['ngAnimate']);
myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$timeout',
  function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.showme = false;
    $scope.callAtTimeOut = function() {
      $scope.showme = false;
    }
    $scope.animateDiv = function() {
      $scope.showme = true;
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.callAtTimeOut();
      }, 5000);
    }

  }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add this jquery: codepen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZYxymO)

```
$('button').click(function() {
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    $('.check-element').fadeOut();}, 3000);
});
```