# Fire an event at the end of ng-show animation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, ng-animate

My AngularJS knowledge is primitive. While answering this [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28593299/2442396), I looked into AngularJS documentation to see if there is any event that fires after `fade-in` animation completes. However I did not find any.

I have created a [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/MyYF0874whQ4Ta8At745?p=info), wherein I am calling a method after 5 secs interval to `fade-out`. Code below:

```
var myApp = angular.module('App',['ngAnimate']);
myApp.controller('MyController',['$scope','$timeout',function($scope,$timeout){
  $scope.showme = false;
  $scope.callAtTimeOut = function()
  {
    $scope.showme = false;
  }
  $scope.animateDiv = function(){
    $scope.showme = true;
    $timeout(function(){
      $scope.callAtTimeOut();
    }, 5000);
  }

}]);
```

Is there a way I can do this without hard-coding 5 secs timeout?

I think I can start looking for certain CSS classes to determine if `fade-in` animation is complete, however it warrants the creation of `directives`.

I am thinking that AngularJS may have defined a built-in event to fire at the end of fade-in animation.

Please help me with your ideas. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try AngularJS 1.4 ngAnimate. It supports Promises and Callbacks for animation start and end: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate